# java util date format in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, date-format, simpledateformat

in my xml file there is something like:

```
DeliveryTime="11.11.2015 00:00:00"
```

Now I only want the date without the time.. How can I use in this case the date format?
I've tried this:

```
 <xsl:variable name="s" select="SimpleDateFormat:new('MMM/dd/yyyy)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="date" select="@DeliveryTime"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="SimpleDateFormat:format($s,$date)" />
```

But I always get an error...

Comment: I could copy my comments verbatim from your last question: Please show the input XML document, a full XSLT stylesheet, show exactly what the output should be (not by describing it, but by showing actual code), elaborate on "gets an error".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I only want the date without the time.

Why don't you simply use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(@DeliveryTime, ' ')"/>
```

This is assuming you want to keep the existing date format.